# Creating a Java Script Array from hidden values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var a1=$("#orderprogress").val().toFixed(2);//a1=50
var a2=$("#poprogress").val().toFixed(2); //a2=70
```

if i want  to create a array like this how would i do it?

```
graphData = new Array(
             [a1 value,'#222222'],//[50,'#222222']
             [a2 value ,'#7D252B']//[70,'#222222']
        );
```

Comment: I think this is an okay question. The user has an issue, has tried something, and has shown code. It might be a trivial fix, but it's still an okay question.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the following code:

```
var a1 = +(+$("#orderprogress").val()).toFixed(2);
var a2 = +(+$("#poprogress").val()).toFixed(2);

graphData = [
    [a1, '#222222'],//[50,'#222222']
    [a2, '#7D252B']//[70,'#222222']
];
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ERccS/4/

This will take the textbox value (a string), convert it to a number, call `toFixed(2)` on it, then convert it back to a number.

Unfortunately (if you care), `"50"` will be displayed as `50` (this happens with trailing `0`s). If you always need 2 decimal places no matter what, take off the first `+` I have in my code - they will be kept as strings and always have 2 decimal places.

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking to do with the `toFixed`. The `.val()` method **always** returns a string. `toFixed` isn't a `String` method - it's a `Number` method. And its result is the original `Number` rounded to a certain number of decimal places (what you pass to the method). In your case, it's `2`.

Comment: I'm fetching  data from server and setting the decimal precision to 2 . My string value is 50.0123123 so I'm reducing it to 50.01

Comment: @user1507789 Sounds good, then yeah, you'll have to use my code above for setting `a1` and `a2`

Comment: .toFixed(2) returns a string. check http://jsfiddle.net/ERccS/1/. you have to cast again to get the result as number. By the way you had given an explanation `toFixed isn't a String method - it's a Number method`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thanks for pointing that out. I forgot that the result was expected to be a number. And I'm not sure what you meant by "By the way you had given an explanation `toFixed isn't a String method - it's a Number method`"

Answer (score 2):

```
graphData = [[a1, '#222222'], [a2, '#7D252B']];
```

Answer (score 2):

Either

```
var graphData = new Array(new Array(a1,'#222222'),new Array(a2 ,'#7D252B'));
```

OR

```
var graphData = [[a1,'#222222'],[a2,'#7D252B']];
```

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hcx4J/6/),

```
var xArray=[];

var a1=$("#orderprogress").val().toFixed(2);//a1=50
var a2=$("#poprogress").val().toFixed(2); //a2=70

InsertIntoArray(a1,'#fff')
InsertIntoArray(a2,'#fff')

function InsertIntoArray(x,y)
{
var yArray=[x,y];

xArray.push(yArray);

}
```

or simply,

```
   var xArray=[];

    var a1=$("#orderprogress").val().toFixed(2);//a1=50
    var a2=$("#poprogress").val().toFixed(2); //a2=70

    xArray.push([a1,"#fff"],[a2,"#fff"]);
```

Comment: The `InsertIntoArray` function seems pointless. Just use `xArray.push([a1, '#fff'])`, etc.

Comment: @TedHopp i just thought that, this would be a cleaner way of doing this, Any way thanks for your attention. :)